# RXJS Wait for All Observables to Complete and Return Results

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to create a RX stream that will execute a list of XHR calls async and then wait for them to complete before going to the next call.

To help explain this could be written like this in normal JS:

```typescript
try {
    await* [
        ...requests.map(r => angularHttpService.get(`/foo/bar/${r}`))
    ];
} catch(e) { throw e }

// do something
```

This is the code I was trying but its running them individually and not waiting for them all to complete before proceeding. (This is a NGRX Effect stream so it is slightly different from vanilla rx).

```typescript
mergeMap(
        () => this.requests, concatMap((resqests) => from(resqests))),
        (request) =>
            this.myAngularHttpService
                .get(`foo/bar/${request}`)
                .pipe(catchError(e => of(new HttpError(e))))
    ),
    switchMap(res => new DeleteSuccess())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**forkJoin**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), it will emit the last emitted value from each of completed observables. The following is an example from the linked documentation:

```typescript
    import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
    import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
    
    const myPromise = val =>
      new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(() => resolve(`Promise Resolved: ${val}`), 5000)
      );
    
    const source = of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    //emit array of all 5 results
    const example = source.pipe(mergeMap(q => forkJoin(...q.map(myPromise))));
    /*
      output:
      [
       "Promise Resolved: 1",
       "Promise Resolved: 2",
       "Promise Resolved: 3",
       "Promise Resolved: 4",
       "Promise Resolved: 5"
      ]
    */
    const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

---

There is also this nice recipe by **Peter B Smith**, also using `forkJoin` for the same propose that I'll just copy/past its content below:

---

Copied from: https://gist.github.com/peterbsmyth/ce94c0a5ddceb99bab24a761731d1f07

---

## Making chained API Calls using @ngrx/Effects

#### Purpose

This recipe is useful for cooking up chained API calls as a result of a single action.

#### Description

In the below example, a single action called `POST_REPO` is dispatched and it's intention is to create a new repostiory on GitHub then update the README with new data after it is created.
For this to happen there are 4 API calls necessary to the GitHub API:

1. POST a new repostiry
2. GET the master branch of the new repository
3. GET the files on the master branch
4. PUT the README.md file

The `POST_REPO's payload contains` payload.repo with information needed for API call 1.
The response from API call 1 is necessary for API call 2.
The response from API call 2 is necessary for API call 3.
The response from API call 3 and `payload.file, which has information needed to update the README.md file, is neccessary for API call 4.

Using `Observable.ForkJoin` makes this possible.

#### Example

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Effect, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { handleError } from './handleError';


import { GithubService } from '../services/github.service';
import * as githubActions from '../actions/github';

@Injectable()
export class GitHubEffects {
  @Effect()
  postRepo$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(githubActions.POST_REPO)
    .map((action: githubActions.PostRepo) => action.payload)
    // return the payload and POST the repo
    .switchMap((payload: any) => Observable.forkJoin([
      Observable.of(payload),
      this.githubService.postRepo(payload.repo)
    ]))
    // return the repo and the master branch as an array
    .switchMap((data: any) => {
      const [payload, repo] = data;
      return Observable.forkJoin([
        Observable.of(payload),
        Observable.of(repo),
        this.githubService.getMasterBranch(repo.name)
      ]);
    })
    // return the payload, the repo, and get the sha for README
    .switchMap((data: any) => {
      const [payload, repo, branch] = data;
      return Observable.forkJoin([
        Observable.of(payload),
        Observable.of(repo),
        this.githubService.getFiles(repo.name, branch)
          .map((files: any) => files.tree
            .filter(file => file.path === 'README.md')
            .map(file => file.sha)[0]
          )
      ]);
    })
    // update README with data from payload.file
    .switchMap((data: any) => {
      const [payload, repo, sha] = data;
      payload.file.sha = sha;
      return this.githubService.putFile(repo.name, payload.file);
    });

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private githubService: GithubService,
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: Nice. I ended up with a similar solution but was hoping there was a better way. Side note: you dont need to spread that array.

Comment: The final link mentioned is 404. Can someone fix or delete it?

Comment: Should be working now @LeeGoddard