# How should I make Ngrx Async Actions resolved in a particular order

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

If I dispatch 3 async actions (with corresponding effect/RESTservice call logic) in a particular order, I CANNOT guarantee they are resolved in the same order.
Because, they are asyncs, some actions are faster/slower than others. It might end up with this :

```
Action 1 Start
Action 1 Complete
Action 2 Start
Action 3 Start
Action 2 Complete
Action 3 Complete
```

For example, I would like to fire 3 actions to update a single record in the database. Once the first one is executed and resolved, I need to update store with latest recorder version number (for concurrency checking). After that, second one can be executed with the up-to-date version number...

I prefer this order for my use case:

```
   Action 1 Start
   Action 1 Complete (store state is up-to-date)
   Action 2 Start
   Action 2 Complete (store state is up-to-date)
   Action 3 Start
   Action 3 Complete (store state is up-to-date)
```

I am thinking to have an queue that includes an collection async Actions, and only one action can be executed at a time . Once the current action is resolved, we move the the next.

Does NgRx support action queue? or any equivalent feature I should use to avoid the race condition?
I would appreciate any suggestions/ideas.
thanks

Comment: I think you need to use the [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator. check if the answer in to the following question is what you are looking for: [RXJS Wait for All Observables to Complete and Return Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666086/rxjs-wait-for-all-observables-to-complete-and-return-results/48666847)

Comment: You could have each effect emit the action to trigger the next effect upon completion.